# Modal view in not centered and no interaction

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, segue, interaction

I am trying to do a segue, but when the segues performs the modal view isn't centered and I am not able to interact with it. Any ideas? I tried setting the superview position and whatnot on viewWillLayoutSubviews, but that didn't change anything.[image]

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 550, 650);
    self.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
}

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PresentJobDetailViewController"]) { 
    [self save:nil]; 
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController; 
    ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; viewController.obj = _obj; 
}
```

Comment: How are you creating your modal view? How are you triggering the segue? Both of those could have a bearing on how the view is being displayed.

Comment: The view is created in the storyboard and I trigger it from the press of a button.

Comment: @user2282932 for your information, `self.view.superview` doesn't mean to access the view which is in the top of all views which user can see. `self.view.superview` is a `superview` for a `view`. it means `self.view` is a `subview` in that `view`.

Comment: If you can show your code, how you are presenting the modal view? try to show as a pageSheet or formSheet. When I see your topView, it looks like you are not using popOver.

Comment: I am setting it as a formSheet. Style is Modal and the presentation is Form Sheet. Transition left at default. Here is the code I have inside the prepareForSegueMethod.  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PresentJobDetailViewController"]) {
        [self save:nil];
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        ViewController *viewController = (ViewController *)[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        viewController.obj = _obj;
    }

Comment: Is there anyone that can help me here? I am still stuck on this